# Android - Layout change from database

Tags: android

I have a project about quiz . I want to get data from database to create question . When user click next button , it go to next question (fetch from database).It has many question so can't create activity for each question . What type of layout should I use and How would I do that ?
Thank for helping ..

Comment: what have u done till now for this!! SO is meant to be solve your problem not a tutorial kind of question. What you are asking is very easy to do, But i am not gonna tell!!

Answer (score 0):

You create a normal layout for a single question, what you have to do later is when the user answers, you change the values of the elements of the layout, for example you change the TextView to the second question. Also, when the user answers, you will save the answer in your database. (You might want to use incremental ID for the questions and answers in order to achieve that in easy way).

Comment: Thank you , it is much easier than I think .

Answer (score 0):

Use can use Normal Layout with one **Button** and **TextView**. Button for moving to next question and TextView for displaying the question.

Use Cursor to get all questions from the database. It will store all the questions. So when ever you clicked the button you can use `question_cursor .moveToNext()`.

```
     Cursor question_cursor = db.getPersonId(this);
        if(question_cursor !=null)
        {
            personid_cursor.moveToFirst();
            String question = question_cursor .getString(Your Value));

                    }
```

Use TextView to display the question.

Hope it helps.